# Visual Studio 2019 F12 to decompiled source for .NET Core projects

Tags: .net-core

I very often use the [Visual Studio F12 to decompiled source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2019#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c) feature. When I do this against framework classes in a **.NET Core** project I very often end up looking at some sort of reference assembly that has no implementation code, just stubs, e.g

[image]

Is there any way of getting it to go straight to the actual implementation code instead?

Comment: That is not a VS feature, you got it from ILSpy.  It is not sophisticated enough to know that it is decompiling a reference assembly.  VS itself only decompiles declarations.  Such assemblies contain no code, they are only meant to provide declarations to the compiler.  At runtime you get the real assembly, traditionally from the GAC.  Breaking the dependency between the two allowed Microsoft to make changes that don't break existing projects, first done at .NET 4.0.  Beyond pointing ILSpy at the right file, consider using .NETCore source code from github.com, comments are useful.

Comment: @HansPassant "That is not a VS feature" - Look at the link in my post https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/go-to-and-peek-definition?view=vs-2019#view-decompiled-source-definitions-instead-of-metadata-c ... it is clearly a VS feature.

Comment: Okay, that's new.  At least they mention ILSpy.

Answer (score 4):

So you see at the top where it lists `.Ref` at the end of the package name? I'm not positive but I suspect this is trimmed down version of the DLL that doesn't include the full source.

If you search for the dll elsewhere you should be able to find the dll with the full source and decompile that with a standalone decompiler.

So for your example you can find the full dll at `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.0.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll`

Personally I prefer using the **free** decompiler offered by JetBrains called [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). It allows you to navigate directly to the decompiled source using F12, however this will only lead you back to where you are stuck now. BUT if you open the path I listed above for the full DLL and open that in dotPeek, you'll get the **full decompiled source code**.

[image: Decompiled Source]
As far as I know there's no way to lookup the actual DLL via keyboard shortcut inside the IDE, you have to find the DLL yourself and open it in a decompiler.

Comment: Programmers tend to get wedded to the tools they are familiar with.  That's pretty normal, but I don't think recommending dotPeek is a great idea.  ILSpy is the better product.  They all try to be what Reflector once was, nobody is done yet.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry, I'm still new to posting here, hope I didn't break a rule or something. I did mention that it was my personal preference. I'll review the rules, and thanks for pointing out that there's a better alternative!

Comment: Thanks @NickHenry, I've used dotPeek in the past. I wish this built-in VS feature did a better job of taking me to the expected place automatically :-)

Comment: @NickHenry so how did you get the path to the full DLL?

Comment: @DanielLiuzzi - try to search it at your "Shared" folder on your "Program Files", e.g. System.Linq.dll could be found at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Packages\System.Linq.4.1.0\lib\net463` folder.

Answer (score 3):

I have a partial solution for this. It's partial because still the **Go to Definition (F12)** won't work for it, but the **Step Into (F11)** option while debugging can successfully step into the actual .NET Core, not just the stub.
The feature is called [Source Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/improving-debug-time-productivity-with-source-link/), I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've downloaded the ILSpy visual studio extension...
There is a way to decompile using a keyboard shortcut.
Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard

[image: Options Window]

Press a set of keys for the keyboard shortcut. (I used ctrl i l).
Click Assign->OK

Pressing the above keyboard shortcut will now open the selected code decompiled in a new window of ILSpy.

Answer (score 2):

They are still working on this feature. There's a [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55834) for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you have JetBranis dotPeeK installed and you cannot see the decompiled file when you press F12 or Ctrl + F12 :

Go to Tools > Option > Resharper Options > External Sources : then enable Decompile Resource
[image]